# R: Count the frequency of every unique character in a column

Tags: r

I have a data frame  `df` which contains a column named `strings`. The values in this column are some sentences.

For example:

```
id    strings
1     "I want to go to school, how about you?"
2     "I like you."
3     "I like you so much"
4     "I like you very much"
5     "I don't like you"
```

Now, I have a list of stop word,

```
["I", "don't" "you"]
```

How can I make another data frame which stores the total number of occurrence of each unique word (except stop word)in the column of previous data frame.

```
keyword      frequency
  want            1
  to              2
  go              1
  school          1
  how             1
  about           1
  like            4
  so              1
  very            1
  much            2
```

My idea is that:

1. combine the strings in the column to a big string.
2. Make a list storing the unique character in the big string.
3. Make the df whose one column is the unique words.
4. Compute the frequency.

But this seems really inefficient and I don't know how to really code this.

Answer (score 1):

One way is using `tidytext`. Here a [book](https://www.tidytextmining.com/tidytext.html#tidyausten) and the code

```
library("tidytext")
library("tidyverse")

#> df <- data.frame( id = 1:6, strings = c("I want to go to school", "how about you?",
#> "I like you.", "I like you so much", "I like you very much", "I don't like you"))

df %>% 
  mutate(strings = as.character(strings)) %>% 
  unnest_tokens(word, string) %>%   #this tokenize the strings and extract the words
  filter(!word %in% c("I", "i", "don't", "you")) %>% 
  count(word)

#> # A tibble: 11 x 2
#>    word       n
#>    <chr>  <int>
#>  1 about      1
#>  2 go         1
#>  3 how        1
#>  4 like       4
#>  5 much       2
```

**EDIT**

All the tokens are transformed to lower case, so you either include `i` in the stop_words or add the argument `lower_case = FALSE` to `unnest_tokens`

Answer (score 1):

At first, you can create a vector of all words through `str_split` and then create a frequency table of the words.

```
library(stringr)
stop_words <- c("I", "don't", "you")

# create a vector of all words in your df
all_words <- unlist(str_split(df$strings, pattern = " "))

# create a frequency table 
word_list <- as.data.frame(table(all_words))

# omit all stop words from the frequency table
word_list[!word_list$all_words %in% stop_words, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `mystring` object and a vector of `stopWords`, you can do it like this:

```
# split text into words vector
wordvector = strsplit(mystring, " ")[[1]]

# remove stopwords from the vector
vector = vector[!vector %in% stopWords]
```

At this point you can turn a frequency `table()` into a `dataframe` object:

```
frequency_df = data.frame(table(words))
```

Let me know if this can help you.

Comment: This is really clear. But how can i put all the unique words in my column to the vector? I am stuck at the beginning.

Comment: I changed the post directly, hope this helps.